# VSTS Build Console application

Tags: tfs, msbuild, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-build-task

Trying to build a solution that contains multiple projects - each producing an executable console app. Using TFS Online (VSTS).

I have a few issues:

1. When I enter the Project value: `$/Applications/iReports/**/*.*proj` it errors with

   > Solution not found using search pattern 'D:\a\3\s\$\Applications\iReports***.*proj'.
2. If I directly reference just one of the projects in the above, it errors with

   > MyReport\MyReport.csproj(73,11): Error MSB4226: The imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets" was not found. Also, tried to find "Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets" in the fallback search path(s) for $(MSBuildExtensionsPath) - "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild" . These search paths are defined in "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe.Config". Confirm that the path in the `<Import>` declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk in one of the search paths.

I am using the MSBuild task and everything is default except Project value which I have described above.

***UPDATE***: Thanks for the responses.

@Daniel - I can build it locally in VS but not the build job in TFS

@Josh - this is the path to the solution and project files in TFS.

Comment: Why can't you just build the solution?

Comment: What is the "$" in your `$/Applications/iReports/**/*.*proj` value? What are you trying to accomplish with that? Which host pool have you selected for your pipeline?

Comment: The second error message indicates that your project are using Visual Studio 2015, while the vsts agent is using Visual Studio 2017. That's also a mismatch you should resolve before moving on.